# Uncaught ReferenceError: vote is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to call a JS function on an HTML button click.

This is my JavaScript:

```js
function vote(counter) {
    var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['user'] ;?>";
    var privPostingWif ="<?php echo $_SESSION['code'] ;?>";
    var postAuthor = '<?php echo $posts[' + counter + ']->author ;?>';
    var permalink = '<?php echo $posts[' + counter + ']->link ;?>';
    steem.broadcast.vote(privPostingWif, username, postAuthor, permalink, 10000, function(err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);

    });
}
```

I have used the NPM run dev command to compile it. Hopefully, the compiled code isn't relevant here.

Then I have my script includes in the head section:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.steemjs.com/lib/latest/steem.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ URL::asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

And the button code in the body section:

```html
<input type="button" value="Capacity Chart" onclick="vote(1);">
```

And when I click the button I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: vote is not defined
>      at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Not sure why I can't access it, even though it's clearly in the file.

Comment: Have you checked whether the script was actually loaded properly?

Comment: Yes, I can see the js file through inspect using my browser.